# Storing multiple images with each image having its own information like size, coordinates etc in C++, opencv

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I have a set of detected objects in a vector and I want to store the information about each detected object like its coordinates, assign an id, keypoints etc. so that I can access the information about each detected object for matching with the detected objects in the next frame.
What should I use in c++, to store or assign such information about each detected object.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a struct or class with the information as variables for that struct or class. E.g.

```
class DetectedObject
{
    public:
    Keypoint         coordinates;
    int              id;
    vector<Keypoint> keypoints;

    ... constructor,destructor,methods,etc...
};
```

you would also need a class for keypoints; maybe something like

```
class Keypoint
{
    public:
    float x;
    float y;

    ...constructor,destructor,methods,etc...
};
```

I suggest you look more into c++ classes as what I wrote was just supposed to give you some intuition on what to do. Hope this helps

Comment: @DimaMaligin depends on what all information you want to store. But KeyPoint is already a class in OpenCV.

Comment: That is very true, and a better option unless you want to store extra stuff inside a keypoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class of information which can contain the information about an object e.g. its id, keypoints, coordinates etc.

```
Class Info
{
    kepoints...
    id....
    etc
}
```

Then for each detected object **(let me call it "detected image" to avoid the confusion between this object and the object of a class)**, make an object of the above class...pass the information about the detected image through that object of class. In this way, you would have a separate object for each detected image. You can access/pass the information about that image through that object.

As soon as you create an object of `Class Info` for a detected image, push it into a vector as shown below:

```
vector<Info> detectedImages;
detectedImages.push_back(object_createdForThisDetectedImage);
```

In this way, you would be able to store all the detected images (detected objects as you mentioned) into a vector.